# Stretching an un-resizeable window

Tags: windows-xp, resolution

I'll get this out of the way and mention that I'm working with a Windows XP computer running legacy applications that cannot be transferred to a VM or updated. It is a POS for a restaurant and their table management software is hardcoded to display at 800x600 windowed. This wasn't a problem before, because the resolution was set to 800x600 and they had no other applications running. Now they've installed Office and another management program for handling a few rooms they rent out, which do not display correctly at 800x600. Some important fields get cut off, etc.

I have tried keeping the 800x600 resolution and running ResizeEnable to shrink the Room Management software, but it's not ideal. All input fields will display but the UI looks awful and some of the labels get cut off from ResizeEnable trying to jam everything in there. I have also tried setting the system resolution to 1024x768, which Excel and the Room Management software display fine in, and used ResizeEnable to make the Restaurant software larger, but scaling the window from 800x600 only adds blank space to the sides. The problem is that the Restaurant software is used with a touchscreen so all the elements are basically images and don't scale like text elements would.

My ideal solution to this (and there may be a better one) would be to keep it at 1024x768 and find a program that instead of scaling a window and moving the elements around, would stretch an entire window regardless of content. Kind of like a magnifier but one that I can bind to just the restaurant software. I don't know if this exists but it's sure proven difficult to find. It would also be handy to have the stretched window persistent so they don't have to keep stretching it each time they power on.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Just throwing this out there but can you use Windows Magnifier intended for hard of seeing users?

Comment: That sounds like a big problem. It also sounds like one that really is begging for an update to the POS software as the correct solution. I know you've mentioned that you can't transfer the computer to a VM, but what about setting up a VM on the desktop to run the POS software and hard coding THAT resolution?

Comment: But, I'm not sure how that would work with the touchscreen. It's the first thing I'd try, though, if that were my problem to solve.